# Understanding the Secure Multi-party circuit for Stable Matching

Tags: cryptography, privacy, hardware

I am reading the following paper:

[MPCircuits: Optimized Circuit Generation for Secure Multi-Party Computation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/275.pdf)

I have the following questions:

1. Why Preference of group1 starts from L_0 where as preference list from group2 starts with L_(n/2+1)?
2. Any reason why they used the priority encoder?
3. Is their anything done for security of preference list ?

[image: hardware for secure stable matching]

Answer (score 0):

1. This naming is only for illustration purposes to differentiate preference lists from two groups. In the Verilog code, they actually start from index 0: 
   https://github.com/sadeghriazi/MPCircuits/blob/705fda8ac6e45a2d67bbdd0c81007507742bd4ae/stable_matching_comb/stable_matching_comb.v#L64
2. You need the priority encoder to identify the 'next free person from group A'. Imagine you have a vector of 0s and 1s and you want to learn the 'index' of the first 0. That's what priority encoder does for you.
3. The security of the preference lists is guaranteed by the underlying secure computation protocol, here the BMR protocol. To use BMR, you need a Boolean circuit that implements the functionality for you. Any input to the circuit is not revealed to other parties during the protocol execution.